How can I use PowerQuery (or basic Excel) to automatically transpose a single column of data into a table?
I have tried Googling and multiple different searches in StackOverflow, but I haven't found a solution to this problem.  I have a website (that requires SSO and login - so no direct queries allowed), that provides period data sets in tabular form.  Whenever I copy from the site and paste into Excel (and I've tried every way possible), it always comes out as a single column of data:



My Data




Header A


Header B


Header C


Data A1


Data B1


Data C1


Data A2


Data B2


Data C2



How do I create a query that can automate a transposing of all of this data into the correct/original tabular format?



Header A
Header B
Header C




Data A1
Data B1
Data C1


Data A2
Data B2
Data C2


Data A3
Data B3
Data C3



I have tried solving this on several phases of this process:
Copy (the way I copy it)
Paste (every way that I can find in Excel to control the pasting of this)
Standard Excel tools
PowerQuery (but I'm limited in my PQ skills)

without an example of the output we can't help. One suggestion is the text-to-columns tool.

Will it always be three columns? If not, how can we tell from the data how many columns there will be?

Use WRAPROWS:
=WRAPROWS(A2:A10,3)

You can change the 3 to the number of columns desired.


If you need to rearrange data in place, use the next macro:
Sub Columnist()
  Dim cc As Long, cr As Long, lc As Long, lr As Long
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
  cc = ActiveCell.Column: lc = ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column
  cr = ActiveCell.Row: lr = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row
  j = cc: k = cr
  For i = cr To lr
    Cells(k, j) = Cells(i, cc)
    j = j + 1
    If j > lc Then
      j = cc: k = k + 1
    End If
  Next
  If j > cc Then k = k + 1
  Cells(k, cc).Resize(lr - k + 1, 1).Clear
End Sub

You need to select the top left cell and copy it to right to have as much columns as necessary:

Then run the macro and get the result:

